# How to generate an alpha image with a color range with PIL?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have a grayscale image and I want to create an alpha layer based on a range of pixel values. I want to know how can I create a fall-off function to generate such image.

The original image is the following:
[image]

I can use the color range in photoshop to select the shadows with fuzziness of 20% [image]

And the resultant alpha channel is the following:

[image]

With fuzziness of 100%:
[image]

How can I generate such alpha channels in python with PIL?
I thought that maybe a subtract, but it does not generates a

The code to generate the image with Numpy and PIL:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

img = np.arange(0,256, 0.1).astype(np.uint8)
img = np.reshape(img, (img.shape[0], 1))
img = np.repeat((img), 500, axis=1)
img = Image.fromarray(img.T)
```

I tried to create a fall-off function from the distance of the pixel values but it does not have the same gradient. Maybe there is a different way?

```
def gauss_falloff(distance, c=0.2, alpha=255):
    new_value = alpha * np.exp(-1 * ((distance) ** 2) / (c**2))
    new_value = new_value.clip(0,255)
    return new_value.astype(np.uint8)

test = img.T / 255
test = np.abs(test - pixel)
test = gauss_falloff(test, c=0.2, alpha=255)
test = Image.fromarray(test)
```

With my code:
[image]

Comment: Your code seems incomplete. It has `img` and unused `imp` (?) and undefined `new_img`

Comment: It is now fixed

Comment: It still doesn't work on line `test = img.T/255`, it says `img` has no attribute `T`. Also, `pixel` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could do that

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

# Create a new image with a transparent background
width, height = 300, 300
image = Image.new('RGBA', (width, height), (255, 255, 255, 0))

# Create a drawing context for the image
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)

# Set the starting and ending colors for the gradient
start_color = (255, 0, 0)
end_color = (0, 0, 255)

# Draw a gradient line with the specified color range
for x in range(width):
color = tuple(int(start_color[i] + (end_color[i] - start_color[i]) * x / width) 
for i in range(3))
draw.line((x, 0, x, height), fill=color)


# Save the image
image.save('gradient.png')
```

This code creates a new image with a transparent background and a drawing context for that image. Then it draws a gradient line on the image with the specified color range. Finally, it saves the image as a PNG file.

Note: The Python Imaging Library (PIL) has been replaced by the Pillow library, which is a fork of PIL. If you are using Pillow, you can use the same code as above, but you need to import the Image and ImageDraw modules from the Pillow package instead of the PIL package.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what I'm looking for is a function that looks for a specified pixel value and between a range create a gradient. In the example the first image is the one I generate, the third image is what I want to get with a range of 20% and the fourth image is with the 100%